# Increase the speed of laravel 5.6 API speed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel 5.6 for creating API for my website. But API response is slow and it is about to taking around 16 sec to load. How can I increase the API response speed?
 I am running below SQL operations inside API call

```
$master_data        =   DB::table('native_visitors_main AS nvm')
                                    ->leftJoin('ad_campaigns AS ac','ac.id','=','nvm.ad_campaign_id')
                                    ->select(
                                            'ac.id as campaign_id',
                                            'ac.campaign_name as campaign_name',
                                            'nvm.current_cpc as cpc',
                                            DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN nvm.gmt_time BETWEEN '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_click"),
                                            DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN nvm.is_unique > 0 AND nvm.gmt_time BETWEEN '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unique_click"),
                                            DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN nvm.is_unique > 0 AND nvm.pixel_status!=''  AND nvm.gmt_time BETWEEN '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ap_click"),
                                            DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN nvm.pixel_status   IN('TY','cake')  AND nvm.pixel_fired_on BETWEEN '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result"),
                                            DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN nvm.is_unique > 0 AND nvm.pixel_status  IN('LP','TY','cake')  AND nvm.pixel_fired_on BETWEEN '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as lp_clicks"),
                                            DB::raw("ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN nvm.gmt_time BETWEEN '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."' THEN nvm.current_cpc ELSE 0 END  ),2) as  total_cpc")
                                        )
                                        ->groupBy('ac.id')
                                        ->havingRaw("total_click >0")
                                        ->havingRaw("campaign_name != ''")
                                        ->get();
```

Comment: is API contains another server request in controller or it have image

Comment: i have updated my question...pls check

Comment: add this after your code `\DB::listen(function($master_data, $bindings, $time) {
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bindings);
    var_dump($time);
});`

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with Laravel. Your query is taking a lot of time to execute. You need to optimize your query using advanced optimization techniques e.g. indexing. You can search google for advance query optimization techniques.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.  We might be able to fix it from that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query is by its own nature, slow to execute.

Taking the reactive approach, we employ caching mechanisms to save the result for future requests.

You may either:

1. Code the cache system manually: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache
2. Rely on a library to do intelligent caching: https://github.com/spiritix/lada-cache